# Disassemble and debug dynamic generated code executed via delegate in c#

Tags: malware, .net

I'm trying to reverse engeneer a malware using dnSpy that at some point do this:

```
delegate IntPtr H7IREAEBYY(string path, IntPtr data);
byte[] array = new byte[]
        { 233, 151, ... }

IntPtr value = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr intPtr = W47PO0IHP8.VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, (uint)array.Length, 12288U, 64U);
Marshal.Copy(array, 0, intPtr, array.Length);
        W47PO0IHP8.H7IREAEBYY h7IREAEBYY = (W47PO0IHP8.H7IREAEBYY)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(intPtr, typeof(W47PO0IHP8.H7IREAEBYY));
h7IREAEBYY(path, intPtr2);
```

When the delegate is executed the debugger step over the delegate and i can't analyze such code, how can i analyze or disassemble the code in the array that is executed through a delegate?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with dnSpy, as the code that is stored in `array` is not managed code but native. So you have to extract that bytes, saved them in a file and analyze spearately with a native disassembler like r2, Ghidra, IDA etc.

As for stepping into, it's the same. You have to use a native debugger and not the one from dnSpy.

Since this is a mixed binary it might be tricky to setup the system in such a way that you could step from one part of the code debugged in dnSpy and to the other that is native.